# Convert path string from unc to uri, replacing slashes with backslashes in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, replace, split

I need to convert a path this UNC. I have searched and search and cannot piece anything together.

```js
"\\NAS_01\GlobalShare\Docs\Customers\2017\S\Smith, John\photo1.jpg"
```

I need to remove the "\NAS_01\GlobalShare\Docs\Customers\" portion of the path and also "photo1.jpg" and end up with:

```js
2017\S\Smith, John\
```

so that I can pass it to the following function:

```js
function getDriveFolderNoCreate(path, rootFolder) {
  
  var name, folder, search, fullpath;
  
  // Remove extra slashes and trim the path
  fullpath = path.replace(/^\/*|\/*$/g, '').replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '').split("/");
  
  // Always start with the main Drive folder
  folder = rootFolder;
  
  for (var subfolder in fullpath) {
    
    name = fullpath[subfolder];
    search = folder.getFoldersByName(name);
    
    if (search.hasNext()) {
        var folder = search.next;
        var folderID = folder.getId();
        return folderID;
    }
  }
}
```

My intention is to return a url to open the Google Drive folder with the same path.

Comment: Use Regex and `string.replace()`

Comment: Thank you for your response @tehhowch.

Comment: I have tried multiple variations of

Comment: I have tried multiple variations of var replacedPath = path.replace(/\\/g, "/"); to no avail. That does work  when I input it it at https://regex101.com/r/UBtjxl/1

Comment: RexExp doesn't work the same in Apps Script as in your browser.  I can confirm that Apps Script will not find a forward slash.  It won't even find it if you loop through every character, or do something like trying to find the character code.  You should report it on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: I was able to remove the forward backslashes, but it will not insert the forward slashes. Looks like I'll need to workaround..

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with a multi-part solution that works very well.

I paste the fill UNC path to cell B2.
This formula is in B3 =Index(split(B2, "\"), 0, 8)
It returns the exact folder name i need.
Then in my gs file:

```js
function findDriveFolder() {
  var pFId = "XYZ1233333333333";
  var input = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("B3").getValue();
  var folders =  DriveApp.getFoldersByName(input); 
  Logger.log("folders: " + folders[0]);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
  var url = folder.getUrl();
  showAnchor("View Folder", url);
  }
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Files Folder");
}
```

I have not implemented the searchFolders part yet that I hope will speed it up. At least it's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script needs your input backslashes to be escaped if you are writing the string yourself (i.e. testing input).

**wrong:**

```
input = "\\NAS_01\GlobalShare\Docs\Customers\2017\S\Smith, John\photo1.jpg"
```

**right:**

```
input = "\\\\NAS_01\\GlobalShare\\Docs\\Customers\\2017\\S\\Smith, John\\photos1.jpg"
```

In Apps Script then, I am able to get the matching portion with the following regex:
`/\d{4}\\[A-Z]\\.+\\/`

i.e:

```
function unc2uri(input) {
  const forwardSlash = String.fromCharCode(47);
  const backSlash = String.fromCharCode(92);

  if(!input)
    input = '\\\\NAS_01\\GlobalShare\\Docs\\Customers\\2017\\S\\Smith, John\\photo1.jpg';
  // Should show \\NAS_01\GlobalShare\Docs\Customers\2017\S\Smith, John\photo1.jpg
  Logger.log(input);
  const matcher = /\d{4}\\[A-Z]\\.+\\/;
  const arrayOfMatches = input.match(matcher);
  // Should show [2017\S\Smith, John\].
  Logger.log(arrayOfMatches);
}
```

To verify, ask for the input string from someplace else (example, `Browser.inputBox`) and pass that to the above as `input`:

```
function readInput() {
  unc2uri(Browser.inputBox("What's the path?"));
}
```

In the inputBox, you would enter the string you expect to be sent, as we view it, i.e. `\\NAS_01\GlobalShare\Docs\Customers\2017\S\Smith, John\photo1.jpg`

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. The input is copied from a legacy program. Is there a way I can escape with apps script? I tried     input = input.replace("\\", "\\"); but that did not work.

Comment: If you are hard-coding the string, i.e. you have to manually type it into the apps script program, then you just need to add the extra slashes. If it is arriving from some other source, and you are reading it with your program (i.e. you never enter that string), the slashes should be encoded into the string properly. Where are you getting your input from? (You should add this information into your question so it is immediately evident)